# How to check if a docker container is done

Tags: docker

I would like to do the following:

1. run a docker container
2. when the 1st process is done run a second container
3. when the 2nd is done run the 3rd

I created a bash script to launch the containers using `nvidia-docker run ..`

How can I check if the first container is done to know if I should start the second one and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use the `-d` flag, the docker call will just wait until the process is done. So you can just call those three containers in a row.

```
set -ex  # fail automatically if any single command fails
nvidia-docker run something command
nvidia-docker run something-else command
nvidia-docker run something-else another command
```

Most of the time you also want to use the `--rm` flag so the container doesn't stay behind.